# Hypermedia links back to home, logout and other common URLs

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, restful-url

A simple application has a home endpoint and in theory you should be able to go from any resource response back to *home*, similar to the idea that you should be able to go from any resource to a *logout* request.  However, you could get a bit carried away here.  Even though it might be possible to change application state from anywhere and always be able to logout or go back to the home page and following the ideas of hypermedia, it would mean every resource response should include links to `/logout` and `/home`.  However, this seems complete overkill. Is there any REST best practise which can guide here?

Comment: Your premise is incorrect. Any resource should provide a set of links to other resources that may be of interest. There is no requirement or even suggestion that every resource provide a link to a home endpoint or an endpoint to log a user out.

Comment: I have re-phrased it